# Sugarcrm : generating contact from inbound emails

Tags: php, email, sugarcrm, inbound

**What i have :**
Sugarcrm enterprise 6.5.14

I have set the inbound email to automatically generate cases under some conditions.
(it is set in Sugar's administration > Inbound email, it's native, i didn't write any code, juste setting it up).
I saw on /modules/InboundEmail/InboundEmail.php the function handleCreateCase() which i think (but please, confirm it) is used to generate cases.

**What i want :**
When a case is generated by an inbound email, the function handleCreateCase() is searching for contact ids and retrieves the good contact with this id :

*snippet of handleCreateCases() :*

```
if($contactIds = $this->getRelatedId($contactAddr, 'contacts')) {
    if(!empty($contactIds) && $c->load_relationship('contacts')) {
         $c->contacts->add($contactIds);
    } // if
} // if
```

Now, i would like to add a "Else" condition : if there is no related contact, then create one.

**My question is..**

How do i code that? **Could i customize the InboundEmail module?** Will it be taken by Sugar?

Thanks a lot for your patience and your time.

Comment: Where are you getting the data to create a new Contact record? All you would have with 100% accuracy is a sending email address. It may be easier and/or more reliable to find Cases without related Contacts, look up their originating emails in the Emails module, and use the "Quick Create" button there to create the Contact with some attempts at pre-populating fields, but this gives you the manual oversight that I think you need for this.

Comment: Hello @MatthewPoer, as i posted the snippet code above, the sender contact's email address is searched into the database. If there is an id, sugar loads the relationship. If not, it does nothing. SO, yes, i have the email address, and sugar does search it. But normally the emails sent to my customer are a result of a form, so we know how the email is set and where the datas are, so i could autopopulate a contact.
My customer wants the contacts not already existing to be AUTOMATICALLY generated, so the QuickCreate button is not the solution. Thanks for the thoughts, it could help somebody else